# Probability Paradox Envelope Switching.

Tags: probability

I have 6 envelopes. They contain $\$2 , \$4 , \$ 8 , \$16 , \$32 $ and $ \$64 $. I line them up in order and then behind your back select two adjacent envelopes uniformly randomly from the five pairs of adjacent envelopes. I then give one to you and one to your opponent and you both look inside. You then have the chance to switch. If you and your opponent both agree then you swap otherwise nothing happens and you both keep your envelopes.

If someone sees $\$64$ they obviously don't switch knowing they cannot do better.

If someone sees $\$32$ they also wont switch because they know they can never do better because 64 doesn't switch.

Likewise if someone sees $\$16$ they shouldn't switch because they cannot do better.

And so on until we reach the $\$2$ case?!? Meaning that if you see $\$2$ you shouldn't switch either?

Where have I gone wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: At $\$2$, you should feel free to offer to switch, though you ought to expect your opponent to decline.  You are in no danger of losing any money though.

Comment: This line of reasoning has an [unexpected-hanging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unexpected_hanging_paradox) kind of feel to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\$2$ person should ask to switch as he knows it is to his advantage.  Your reasoning is sound to say nobody else should agree to switch.  If someone does have $\$2$ the other will have $\$4$ and will decline, so no switch will happen.